# i want to change negative values to positive in a column of dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

[image]

i tried by using loop but it didnt get updated to the df

```
a=df['differnce']  
for row,value in enumerate(a):
    if(value>0):
        value==value
    else:
        value=-value
    print(value)
```

output came what i wanted but it does not get updated to the df
o/p by loop

```
41.0
6.0
3.0
189.0
2.0
7.0
59.0
171.0
96.0
20.0
45.0
226.0
161.0
120.0
55.0
40.0
62.0
317.0
36.0
5.0
93.0
3.0
880.0
```

Comment: Can you please use full stops and line breaks when writing sentences? Thanks. Also, please format your posts properly in future.

Comment: Also, use `abs`: `df['difference'] = df['differnce'].abs()`